# When generating .java files in Java by using wsimiport on .wsdl file, is there a way to specify the source code version?

Tags: java, wsdl, version, wsimport, generated-code

I'm generating `.java` files using wsimport in the command line as follows:

```
C:\temp>"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\wsimport" -d . -p com.package.name -keep -extension -Xnocompile File.wsdl
```

I'm successfully generating `.java` files from the `.wsdl` files I'm giving it, but the `.java` files' source version is at least 5.0 as it includes varargs [`function(Integer... myInts)`] and annotations (`@WebServiceClient(`...`)` etc.).

It's easy enough to comment out the annotations, but the varargs are proving a little more difficult to convert for compliance to my source version (1.3). Is there a simple way to tell wsimport to generate source code at a certain compliance level? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to the original question since I was unable to determine a viable way to change the outputted source code version, however, I found a workaround.

My original desire was to include the generated source files into my project and compile them myself. If instead I removed the `-Xnocompile` from the above command, making it:

```
C:\temp>"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\wsimport" -d . -p com.package.name -keep -extension File.wsdl
```

it instead outputs the necessary `.class` files to interact with this particular web service. It removes my ability to compile the code myself, but the class files are no longer code-version dependent, so they were perfectly compatible with my project, and simply needed to be included in the build path.